# C++ Initializing Struct Without Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have a struct in C++

```
typedef struct DIFColor
{
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;


} DIFColor;
```

And am trying to initialize it like this:

```
DIFColor d = new DIFColor();

d.r = r;
d.g = g;
d.b = b;
```

But the compiler complains about not being able to convert a pointer to a regular variable. What pointer? From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914422/proper-way-to-initialize-c-structs) I thought you could simply create a new struct without having to deal with pointers and dynamic memory allocation with `new`. Does it have something to do with the fact that I am initializing the struct like one would in C, instead of using a constructor?

```
error: conversion from 'DIFColor*' to non-scalar type 'DIFColor' requested
```

Comment: There are many questions trying to do this. Why don't people read tutorials before using the language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
DIFColor d = { r, g, b };
```

Answer (score 3):

The operator `new` will return a pointer to your struct. If you want to declare the object on the **heap**

```
DIFColor* d = new DIFColor;
d->r = r;
d->g = g;
d->b = b;
```

Or to declare it on the **stack** don't use `new`.

```
DIFColor d;
d.r = r;
d.g = g;
d.b = b;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use dynamic allocation without reason, and there is no reason in your code, so remove `new`:

```
DIFColor d = new DIFColor();
```

replace with

```
DIFColor d;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `new` keyword in

```
DIFColor d = new DIFColor();
```

creates a pointer. You should either write

```
DIFColor d = {r,g,b}; // allocate on stack
```

or

```
DIFColor * d = new DIFColor(); // make a pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

**new** operator returns a **pointer**.

So, correct syntax would be:

```
DIFColor* d = new DIFColor();
```